# worklight studio 6.1 jquery widgets discovery failed

Tags: jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

In Design perspective, when displaying my html main file, in the palette view, the jquery mobile widgets does not show in Worklight studio 6.1.

**It doesn't work with any version of jQueryMobile greater than 1.3.0. But It's ok with one application over 4 using version 1.3.0.**

Here is the pop-up error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Discoverying jQuery Mobile widgets for /MyProject/apps/MyApp/common/MyApp.html".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How to solve the issue?
thanks

Comment: Do you still have the entry in the error log related to the exception you posted? You can find it in the Error Log view. Also, do you happen to have multiple versions of jQuery in your application's common folder?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention in the question the jQuery Mobile version you are using.

Worklight Studio's RPE (Rich Page Editor) will not work with jQuery Mobile 1.4, may fail with 1.3.2. It will work with 1.3.1.

You can continue using any version you'd like, but if using the RPE, take note of the above.
There is no workaround.

If your issues are different, then please, be more descriptive when asking questions.
"sometimes works, sometimes doesn't" is not helpful.

Comment: for more information, the project was upgraded from a previous 6.0 version.

Comment: @ptitjuju69 if you create a new project with a new hybrid application in Worklight Studio 6.1 and give it jQuery 1.4 initially, does the palette for the new application page have jQuery mobile widgets?